# E: Repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' changed its 'Origin' value from 'Google, Inc.' to 'Google LLC'

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, apt-get, apt

When I `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` my Ubuntu system, I get the following error message regarding fetching Google Chrome updates.  This only started happening a few days ago.

```sh
E: Repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' changed its 'Origin' value from 'Google, Inc.' to 'Google LLC'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
```

The error message clearly shows that this has to do with [Google changing its name](https://techcrunch.com/2017/09/04/google-parent-alphabet-forms-holding-company-xxvi-to-complete-2015-corporate-reorganization/) from *Google, Inc* to Google *LLC*.  The error message shows what's wrong, but does not tell us what command to run to fix this problem.

How can I accept this change explicitly as the message says?

Comment: This seems to have happened again a few hours ago, in this case to `http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb`, i.e. the Chrome browser repository. It would be nice to be able to confirm such a change from a Google official page.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant It is closed because it is off topic for Stack Overflow. It might be on-topic on SuperUser or AskUbuntu

Answer (score 240, accepted):

## Solution

Run:

```sh
$ sudo apt update
```

Note this is `apt` and **not** `apt-get`

Then enter `y` to accept the change:

```sh
E: Repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' changed its 'Origin' value from 'Google, Inc.' to 'Google LLC'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
Do you want to accept these changes and continue updating from this repository? [y/N] y
```

The error will not show up again.  You need to run `sudo apt-get update`  and `sudo apt-get upgrade` as usual to get your updates.

## Details

As pointed out in the question, this error message is meant to ensure that the new entity named **Google LLC** you are fetching Google Chrome updates from is the same as **Google, Inc.** that your system trusts and knows its signature.  By accepting the change, you are asking your system to trust **Google LLC** and accept Google Chrome updates from it in the future.

Comment: Is it ok if I add a hint to not mix up `apt` with `apt-get` to your question (obvious, however not for me and possibly someone else)?

Comment: Why doesn't `apt-get` update work for this? Weird edge-case to require running `apt` instead

Comment: Is there a way to force the changes to be accepted in a non interactive way?

Comment: That's strange.  If this change happened earlier this year, why am I only running into this today (Nov 6, 2018)?  Either way, fix works.

Comment: _italic_ apt-get may be considered as lower-level and "back-end", and support other APT-based tools. apt is designed for end-users (human) and its output may be changed between versions.

See details here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/445384/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-and-apt-get

Comment: @Stéphane Because it was a different repository. This question was about `chrome-remote-desktop`, while today `chrome` changed.

Comment: @jmreicha You can _automate_ it via the **-y** switch like: `sudo apt update -y`

Answer (score 11):

Run

```
apt-get update -y --allow-releaseinfo-change
```

This allows installation even if  in new release of the application its information changed

Comment: Just out of curiosity: `apt-get update --allow-releaseinfo-change` worked fine for me. Where is the `-y` flag used?

Comment: -y is for yes/no type questions on terminal. you can avoid it

Answer (score 3):

I had to download the key file from Google https://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/ and import it into the software sources authentication.

Upon re-running Sudo Apt Update I was given the option to respond to the question

> Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
>   Hit:9 http://packages.linuxmint.com tara Release
>   Hit:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
>   E: Repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release'
>   changed its 'Origin' value from 'Google, Inc.' to 'Google LLC' N: This
>   must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be
>   applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details. Do you want to accept
>   these changes and continue updating from this repository? [y/N] y
>   Get:11 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64
>   Packages [1,130 B] Fetched 2,892 B in 4s (705 B/s)
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   All packages are up-to-date.

Hope this helps somebody

Comment: Many thanks. The accepted solution did NOT work until I did THIS solution and installed the key. Wow that was gnarly!